# Blank page with Electron Application

Tags: angularjs, animation, electron

I have a big issues with electron.
It's seems to "Crash" when html animation's fired. So exactly electron show me a blank page (html, localstorage, scripts ecc were deleted), we have no logs in console and terminal.

Is there a way to debug verbose application?

Somebody can help me?

EDIT: i have test a lot and i found problem. I use angular-ui-router and when i use a tag `<a>` some links works, another crash app (blank screen)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your code here so we can help you!

Comment: Hello, it is an entire private project and we can't share @Cᴀʟʟᴏᴅᴀᴄɪᴛʏ. Do you know solution for this?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you without anything more specific, there could be hundreds of different problems

Comment: this user have similar problem https://github.com/twolfson/google-music-el (i not use this package).

Comment: @Cᴀʟʟᴏᴅᴀᴄɪᴛʏ EDIT: i have test a lot and i found problem. I use angular-ui-router and when i use a tag `<a>` some links works, another crash app (blank screen)